# Scrum plugin with Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, scrum

Could you please give me a scrum plugin compatible with Redmine 3.0.0.
I tried [scrum2b](https://github.com/scrum2b/scrum2b), but I got this error when I run the server:

```
undefined method `sanitize_forbidden_attributes' scrumb2
```

I also tried [Redmine Backlogs](http://www.redminebacklogs.net/), but when I ran:

```
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate
```

it showed this error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Backlogs::IssuePatch::RbIssueHistory
```

Is there any other plugin or an alternative to one of these?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free and working redmine 3.x compatible plugin available at

https://redmine.ociotec.com/projects/redmine-plugin-scrum

Version v0.13.0 was released just a few days ago. 
I used it in an earlier version at my old company and it has some useable features.

Comment: The people who review these answers should read them first. The questioner is asking WHERE something is. A link is the most appropriate was to answer this. The link IS the answer. The link is not pointing to where to find the answer. If it were, then the Wes would be correct.

Comment: This plugin - https://redmine.ociotec.com/projects/redmine-plugin-scrum gives me Unknown validator: 'DateValidator' when I trying to do "bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production" after unpacking it. Could you please tell what is it and how to cure? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There are no scrum plugins adapted for use with Redmine 3.x.
At this moment you can try Agile plugin by redminecrm ( http://www.redminecrm.com/projects/agile/pages/1 ), it has free version with limited functionality. Also there is Easy Agile Board ( http://www.easyredmine.com/online-store/easy-redmine-plugins/easy-agile-board ), but it has no free version, only commercial

Comment: I think the point of these spaces is to provide open source solutions not paid solutions. Redmine is totally open source so hawking paid solutions is a bit not cool.

Comment: I fully agree with you, @shaneonabike :)